# Forbidden error when using too long URL string

Tags: .htaccess, server, centos7

I am getting a 403 error when my URL string it too long. See the example below.

I want to redirect it to an error page instead of displaying the default server message.

I tried the below code in .htaccess but that does not work:

```
ErrorDocument 403 /403.php
```

Sample url:

https://example.com/111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111%20whschecks%20whschecks%20whschecks%20whschecks%20whschecks%20whschecks%20whschecks%20whschecks%20whschecks%11111111111111111111111%20whschecks%20whschecks%20whschecks%20whschecks%20whschecks%20whschecks%20whschecks%20whschecks%20whschecks%20whschecks%20whschecks%20whschecks%20whschecks%20whschecks%20whschecks

Comment: see here https://serverfault.com/questions/120397/max-length-of-url-257-characters-for-mod-rewrite